# How do I add the output of a for-loop to a list in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, for-loop

I'm looking to iterate over a list of tuples and extract the second value from each tuple. I'd then like to add these values to a new list.

Each tuple in my list consists of a string and an int:

```
y = List((this, 1), (is, 2), (a, 3), (test, 4)
```

I can successfully iterate over each tuple and extract the int using:

```
for (x <- y) {

val intValue = x._2

println(intValue)

}
```

This gives me

```
1

2

3

4
```

I'm then looking to add those values to a list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `val result = list.map(tuple > tuple._2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `for` here, a simple `map` will do:

```
y.map(_._2)
```

The `map` function creates a new `List` from the old one by calling a function on each element of the `List`.

The function `_._2` is a shorthand for `x => x._2`. This just returns the second value in the tuple, which is the `Int` you want to extract.

Comment: Understood, thanks Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function as @Tim explained or just use `yield` like in:

```scala
val list = for ((_,b) <- y) yield b
```